# Running more than one spiders one by one

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I am using Scrapy framework to make spiders crawl through some webpages. Basically, what I want is to scrape web pages and save them to database. I have one spider per webpage. But I am having trouble to run those spiders at once such that a spider starts to crawl exactly after another spiders finishes crawling. How can that be achieved? Is scrapyd the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrapyd is indeed a good way to go, [max_proc](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#max-proc) or [max_proc_per_cpu](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#max-proc-per-cpu) configuration can be used to restrict the number of parallel spdiers, you will then [schedule](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#schedule-json) spiders using scrapyd rest api like:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider
```

Comment: i have two spiders: spider1 and spider2. Now how to start doing it?

Comment: But "scrapy deploy" doesn't work. Say "Usage
=====
  scrapy deploy [options] [ [target] | -l | -L <target> ]

deploy: error: Unknown target: default
"

Comment: And where is schedule.json file? Or do I have to create one? @Guy Gavriely

Comment: A browse of the rest of the scrapyd documentation may prove useful: http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/